# hasClass is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My function with a hasClass-Method do not work. I don´t find the error. Any tips? Thank you!

The li-Element:

```
<li id="members-my" class="no-ajax"><a href="/dosomething/"><?php printf( __('do something') ) ?></a></li>
```

My function:

```
jq('li#members-my').click( function(event) {
if ( jq(this).hasClass('no-ajax') 
        return;
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is the result of a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common mistake with jQuery is selectors using #, it assumes there is only one element on the page with that ID due to HTML standards, you'll likely want to use `li.members-my` and put the members-my in the class attribute and add the anchor tag to your click event, since that's ultimately what you're trying to control.

Also, curly-braces are your friend.  They make the code more maintainable and easier to read.

```
jq('li.members-my a').click( function(event) {
    if ( jq(this).parent().hasClass('no-ajax') 
    {
        return; 
    }
}
```

That should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
jq('li#members-my').click( function(event) {
if ( jq(this).hasClass('no-ajax'))// forget to close if ")" 
        return;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to a closing parenthesis )

```
if ( jq(this).hasClass('no-ajax') )
```